# Will $"n"$ linear transformations applied to $0$ always remain $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ and let $x = x_1 + 0$ where $x_1 \in W_1$ and $0 \in W_2$.

If I have $n$ linear transformations denoted as $L_i:V \to V$ for $i = 1, \cdots , n$ and I compose these $n$ linear transformations in any combination and then apply this composition of transformations on $x$

e.g. $L_1 \circ L_2 \circ \cdots \circ L_n (x)$

will I always end up with something that is either $0 + 0 = 0$ or $y_1 + 0$ where $y_1 \not= 0 \in W_1$ or is it possible to end up with a nonzero term for the element contained in $W_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a nonzero element for $W_2$; here's an example:

Write $\mathbb{R}_2=W_1\oplus W_2$ where $W_1=\text{span}\{(1,0)\}$ and $W_2=\text{span}\{(0,1)\}$. Then let $L$ be rotation by $\pi/2$, and you see that $(1,0)\in W_1$ but $L(1,0)=(0,1)\in W_2$.

The type of subspaces you want where this will happen are called $L$-invariant subspaces (which depends on the linear transformation $L$). Then you get the result you were thinking of.